# Don't have a permissions in folder

Tags: permissions, directory

Output from iname is:

```
tomsvk@Andromeda:/srv/www$ namei -l /srv/www/html/
f: /srv/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     srv
drwxr-sr-x www-data www-data www
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data html
```

As you can see folders belongs to group www-data.

```
tomsvk@Andromeda:/srv/www$ grep 'www-data' /etc/group
www-data:x:33:tomsvk
```

And I am member of group www-data, but if I run command:

```
tomsvk@Andromeda:/srv/www$ rm -rf html/
rm: cannot remove 'html/': Permission denied
```

I just don't have a permissions, why?

Comment: First `whoami` and second try `sudo`

Comment: also, if you notice you don't have write permissions on this folder to anyone but the owner - `www-data`

Comment: I don't want to use sudo

Comment: Then `chown root:root -R /srv/www/html/` as `www-data` (or sudo). `-R` is for recursive.

Comment: But that command will change ownership of that folder to root? I just want that ONLY users in group www-data have a permissions in /srv/www/* without using sudo

Comment: Then you do.... but to run `rm -rf html` you need to be logged in as `www-data` (su www-data). Ususally PHP and NodeJS run with that permission on the server.

Comment: Hah? If folder /srv/www/* belongs to www-data then everybody in group www-data should have a permission.

Comment: And user `www-data` not only the group, notice it appears here twice `drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data html`